# Good linq query approach to write Queries which are based on DateTime clause

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I need to fetch Previous Month Invoice from database for a particular user based on his/her relationship number.
I have come up with below linq query.

*// step 1: fetching Bill number based on relationship number and OrderByDescending clause*

 
**

```
var query = context.Billings 

 .OrderByDescending(c => c.BillGenerationDate)
                               .Where(c => c.CAFNO == caf)
                               .Select(c => c.BillNo)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

**
*//step 2 : step 1 result have the bill number which was the last(or highest) filtered by //BillGeneration date*

```
var bill = (from b in context.Billings
                            where b.BillNo == query
                            select b).FirstOrDefault();
```

step 2 will result the full bill information required.

OR

Other way :

```
var myresult = (from c in context.Billings
                            where c.CAFNO == caf
                            orderby c.BillGenerationDate descending
                            select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

I feel the above query can be re-written in better way. Looking for suggestion to re-write the above query in more efficient manner.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Update due to `BillGenerationDate` being Nullable

Your current query would give you the last billing information available not the previous months invoice. To get the previous month succinctly you could do the following.

```
var invoice = context.Billings
                     .FirstOrDefault( 
                         c => c.CAFNO == caf && 
                              (c.BillGenerationDate ?? new DateTime()).AddMonths(1).Month == DateTime.Now.Month &&
                              (c.BillGenerationDate ?? new DateTime()).AddMonths(1).Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
```

However this would not guarantee any order if you have more than one invoice per month, to which you could just add in the ordering phrase again.

```
var invoice = context.Billings
                     .OrderByDescending(c => c.BillGenerationDate)
                     .FirstOrDefault( 
                         c => c.CAFNO == caf && 
                              (c.BillGenerationDate ?? new DateTime()).AddMonths(1).Month == DateTime.Now.Month &&
                              (c.BillGenerationDate ?? new DateTime()).AddMonths(1).Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
```

Note: This is not really any different to your above second query (apart from the additional month filter) as the `FirstOrDefault(Func<T,Bool)` overload acts like a composed `Where(Func<T,Bool>).FirstOrDefault()` so your choice on which is more readable.

Comment: Hi user1793607, i am getting error 'ambiguous invocation' at .FirstOrDefault and cannot apply operator '+' to operands of type System.Nullable<System.DateTime> and int at c.BillGenerationDate +1

Comment: @coddey for the second one are ensure you are getting the `.Month` on both dates as it sounds like one is missing, this should hopefully sort out the first problem (as the type inference should be well formed)

Comment: @coddey also if your `BillGenerationDate` is nullable then you will need to provider a default value to check against...